# How to clean this code up? Insert every four posts into a row with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, refactoring, modulus, code-cleanup

I currently have this piece of code:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    @foreach($contest->submissions as $submission)
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="/contests/{{ $contest->id }}/submissions/{{ $submission->id }}">
                {!! HTML::image('/images/' . $submission->filename) !!}
            </a>
        </div>
        @if($i % 4 == 0)
            </div><div class="row">
        @endif
    <?php $i++; ?>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

I'm stuffing 4 submission at a time into a row kind of how I would do it with wordpress posts. Using the modulus operator to check the remainder.

This code feels really hacked and piece together though. I'm using laravel 5 can anybody help clean this up further and make it a bit more compact and neater looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, it's doesn't feel hacked, you're just displaying a collection in a normal way. I can suggest a couple of changes, but there's no absolute need for them:

**1.** Get rid of the manual declaration and incrementation of the `$i` variable, since you already have access to the index of the collection from the `foreach` statement:

```
@foreach($contest->submissions as $i => $submission)
    ...
@endforeach
```

**2.** Use a [named route](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#named-routes) for you URL (it will make it easy to make changes to the URL structure only to the route definition, and avoid the need to go through every place it's used in order to change it):

```
Route::get('/contests/{contestId}/submissions/{submissionId}', ['as' => 'contest.submissions', ...]});
```

The final result would look something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach ($contest->submissions as $i => $submission)
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <a href="route('contest.submissions', [$contest->id, $submission->id])">
                {!! HTML::image('/images/' . $submission->filename) !!}
            </a>
        </div>
        @if (($i + 1) % 4 == 0)
            </div><div class="row">
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Just because Laravel is expressive and concise, it doesn't mean you can do everything in it with two lines of code.

---